# What would be an ideal mysql database strcture for a multi-level subscription web application?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

Currently I am developing a system that accepts multi-level subscribers. With Laravel 5.8, MySQL.

The idea is,

1. An user (A) will signup with the system.
2. This user can suggest N number of his friends (B,C,D,...).
3. And B, C, D,.. can suggest N number of friends them-self after signup with the system.
4. Now A have his subscribers and his subscriber's subscribers.
5. Note, B or C or D,.. also can include A as their friend.

   ```
                          A
                          |
                 /  /   /   \   \   \
                B   C   D    L   M   N
                |       |
             /  |  \    |
            L   A   D   |
                        |
                     /  |  \
                    K   L   M
                            |
                     /  /  / \  \  \
                    A  B  C   P  Q  R
   ```

therefore:

1. A's network is the major network.
2. both B and M can access all of the members because they have A in their list.
3. L don't have any list
4. can access all users because M is friend of D and M is friend with A.

The Structure cannot be considered as hierarchical.
I guess, Many to many relationship and join table concept needs to be implemented.
MySQL Procedure needs to be used to retrieve information.

Requirements

1. I need to store this relational structure in mysql DB
2. I should be able to retrieve unique users for any given users (MySQL Procedure).

**I hope the I can get a possible suggestions and advise to build this system properly. Thank you.**

Comment: what have you tried so far? this question is both too broad and primarly opinion based IMHO since there are many different possible solutions and all have pros and cons

Comment: Thank you for responding & for welcoming. Unfortunately I couldn't think of a way other than explaining the problem. Basically I am stuck at designing the Database entity and the tables and a logic to build the controller to store and retrieve the data that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could store tree by adding `parent_id` column. Than, use cache to store which users (for example) user C is subscribed to (M, D, A).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It will be great help if you can elaborate your answer. Also, what I need to know is, If I pass D user then I wanted to know who are the users in his network, please note that D -> M ->A now since A has all the users now D can access all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a task for graph database. Mysql is not really a great solution to be used here. You 100% will have problems with perfomance. As option, you can store only relationships in graph database (column ids), and retrieve actual data from mysql.

I know that i am a bit late, but someone can find this question through google.